# How to show balance ZERO by default when someone new makes an account?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a page which shows a `user` how much balance he/she has. I put that balance in admin page. But when somebody makes an account first time, I want to show them their `balance zero`. How to do it?

**models.py**

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Balance'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner} Balance'
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def balance(request):
    total = Balance.objects.get(owner=request.user)
    return render(request, 'nextone/balance.html', {'amount': total.amount})
```

**HTML page**

```
<h2>Your Balance is Rs. {{amount}}</h2
```

Comment: How do you make sure a balance is created when a user signs up?

Comment: Are you sure you want a ForeignKey here ? This means a given user can have virtually millions of balances...

Comment: When a user will sign up, I will see it in admin page. But I want to show him his balance zero at first by default.

Comment: ForeignKey is for owner that which username has this amount. Please answer the relevant question.

Comment: @Housi: but modeling is a very relevant aspect. In fact most problems start with bad modeling, since then that needs to be fixed in the forms, views, signals, etc. and eventually it results in a lot of extra logic, that usually is still less robust than modeling something properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all it might be worth to slightly alter your model, and use a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) here. This is in essence a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), but with a `unique=True` constraint, such that a user can have at most *one* `Balance`, not multiple ones. Furthermore it is advisable to use [**`get_user_model`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model) instead of a reference to the `User` class, since if you later change your user model, it will now refer to the new model. In fact using a custom user model with a balance might be a better modeling choice, since then there is never a "glitch" when a `User` exists, but a related `Balance` does not (yet) exists.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Balance(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Balance'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner} Balance'
```

In our view we can obtain the related balance with `request.user.balance` (this is due to the logic of a `OneToOneField`). Since that can, strictly speaking, fail, we might want to pass `None` in case it fails, like:

```
@login_required
def balance(request):
    try:
        balance = request.user.balance
    except Balance.DoesNotExist:
        balance = None
    return render(request, 'nextone/balance.html', {'balance': balance})
```

Now we can render this with:

```
{% if balance.amount %}
    <h2>Your Balance is Rs. {{ balance.amount }}</h2>
{% else %}
    <h2>balance zero</h2>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: When I makemigrations, it works but it does not run when I migrate. Instead it gives me error.

Comment: @Housi: well that makes sense if some of your views use for example `balance_set`, etc.

Comment: `File "C:\Users\Bilal\Envs\trial\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 603, in _alter_field
    exclude=meta_index_names,
  File "C:\Users\Bilal\Envs\trial\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 1129, in _constraint_names
    if type_ is not None and infodict['type'] != type_:
KeyError: 'type'`

Comment: I didn't understand. This is the error after migrate.

Comment: Will you answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for fields, with the `default` keyword argument, like so.

```py
   amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

That will give the `amount` field a value of 0, whenever not explicitly set otherwise.

Comment: Hey man, I want to show them balance zero in html page, whenever somebody sign up an account. This is not showing. Whenever I assigns some values, it shows otherwise it gives me ```Balance matching query does not exist.```

Comment: @Housi, that's because the amount variable has no value. Setting it to 0 will show you 0 in the html page

Comment: How could I set it 0 by default for new registered user? I am confused in this stage.

Comment: Just setting the keyword argument `default=0` in the DecimalField will make every new Balance object initialize with 0 amount, unless otherwise given.

Comment: @Housi If you want to also make a new balance object whenever a user registers, I suggest looking into signals and making your own customuser model. Also, you might want to use a OneToOneField instead of foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

use attribute default=0 in your model field